# Icons Appear on TabActivitys in Android 2.3.4 but do not on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-tabactivity

I have created a android App with a TabHost and TabActivity.  On Android 2.3.4 the Icons appear on my tab but on Android 4.2.2 they do not.  Here is my  TabHost Activity code.  And All the icons are in the res.drawable folder.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
private static MainActivity instance = null;
/**
 * This is the IO Singleton Instance
 * 
 */
public static MainActivity sharedInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new MainActivity();
    }
    return instance;
}

private TabHost tabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tabHost = getTabHost();

    //Tab for Main Menu
    TabSpec menuSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
    menuSpec.setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_menu));
    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    menuSpec.setContent(menuIntent);

    //Tab for Evacuation Routes
    TabSpec evacSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Evacuation Routes");
    evacSpec.setIndicator("Evacuation Routes", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon29));
    Intent evacIntent = new Intent(this, EvacRouteTableActivity.class);
    evacSpec.setContent(evacIntent);

    //Tab for Shelters
    TabSpec shelterSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Shelter Routes");
    shelterSpec.setIndicator("Shelter Routes", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shelter));
    Intent shelterIntent = new Intent(this, ShelterActivity.class);
    shelterSpec.setContent(shelterIntent);

    //Tab for Fueling Stations
    TabSpec fuelSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Refueling Routes");
    fuelSpec.setIndicator("Refueling Routes", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fillingstation));
    Intent fuelIntent = new Intent(this, FuelStopActivity.class);
    fuelSpec.setContent(fuelIntent);

    //Tab for the Map
    TabSpec mapSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map");
    mapSpec.setIndicator("Map", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fillingstation));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapViewActivity.class);
    mapSpec.setContent(mapIntent);        

    tabHost.addTab(menuSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(evacSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(shelterSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(fuelSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(mapSpec);


}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void addTabs(TabHost tHost){



    //Tab for the Map
    TabSpec mapSpec = tHost.newTabSpec("Map");
    mapSpec.setIndicator("Map", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fillingstation));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapViewActivity.class);
    mapSpec.setContent(mapIntent);        



    tHost.addTab(mapSpec);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

My layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Have you tryed using your own view with setIndicator(View view)?

Comment: No I haven't can you give me an example?

Comment: This might do the trick: http://ericharlow.blogspot.dk/2010/10/experience-customizing-androids-tab.html

Comment: I had already tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: I guess deprecated turned into action for the legacy tabs. You'll have to implement your own tabs or use the new fragment tabs.